# php SQL: Select AND Group results according to different fields, depending on criteria

Tags: php, sql, group-by, case

I am creating a table to display a summary of many different projects, some of which are by country and some by region (multiple regions for one country), but there are only 2 countries that have multiple regions (where ADMIN0ID = 23 or 24)... so in those cases, I need to select and group results based on ADMIN1. The hierarchy of the source table is ADMIN0ID, ADMIN0, ADMIN1ID, ADMIN1, ADMIN2ID, ADMIN2, where anything ending in "ID" is numeric but the corresponding field without "ID" is text. Here is my rudimentary attempt to get the Project names, without any of the summary data:

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN (ADMINOID=24 OR ADMIN0ID=23) THEN ADMIN1 ELSE ADMIN0) AS Project
FROM GTMP_PROGRESS
GROUP BY
(CASE WHEN (ADMIN0ID=24 OR ADMIN0ID=23) THEN ADMIN 1 ELSE ADMIN0)
```

Please help me!

Comment: And what is the problem with your query?

Answer (score 2):

Is this the query you want?

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN ADMIN0ID in (23, 24) THEN ADMIN1 ELSE ADMIN0 END) AS Project
FROM GTMP_PROGRESS
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN ADMIN0ID in (23, 24) THEN ADMIN1 ELSE ADMIN0 END);
```

If so, the primary problem was the lack of `end` in the `case` statement.

Comment: This works: SELECT (CASE WHEN (ADMIN0ID =23 OR ADMIN0=24) THEN ADMIN1 ELSE ADMIN0 END) AS Project
    FROM GTMP_PROGRESS
    GROUP BY (CASE WHEN (ADMIN0ID =23 OR ADMIN0=24) THEN ADMIN1 ELSE ADMIN0 END);

Comment: Good catch on the `END` thing!

Comment: wait! It only works for where ADMIN0ID=23, but didn't work for the data where ADMIN0ID=24...

Comment: @beck777 . . . That is really strange because the `in` statement is treating both values equivalently.

Comment: My mistake. I adjusted the query because the IN statement wasn't working. But I think it was because of the "O" versus "0". Sorry and thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you got some error about "unknown column" or something. In the future, when you ask a question, it would be helpful to be specific about any errors you got, or wrong query results, and how that's different from what you expected to get.

I see at least this problem in your query:

Zero (0) is different from the capital letter 'O'. You're using 'O' in one place where you should have 0.

```
... CASE WHEN (ADMINOID=24 OR ADMIN0ID=23 ...
                    ^              ^
                    O              0
```

Comment: Good catch... not saying I didn't bang my head on my desk one or two times.